# SPARK - How to force error on sc.parallelize

Tags: apache-spark

**Question:**

This statement always gives the right result, no matter how much paralleziation provided. Why does it always give the correct result?

Reading a big file or mapPartitions approach will result in minor loss of accuracy, why not here? It must be simple, but I cannot see it.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),5)   
rdd.sliding(2).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reading a big file or mapPartitions approach will result in minor loss of accuracy,

It won't. Result is exact independent of the source.

Answer (score 0):

From Hortonworks:

sliding() keeps track of the partition index, which in this case corresponds to the ordering of the unigrams.

```
 Compare rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (i, p) => p.map { e => (i, e) } }.collect() and rdd.sliding(2).mapPartitionsWithIndex { (i, p) => p.map { e => (i, e) } }.collect()
```

to help with the intuition.